# Sourcing JS file in shinyapp for D3.js plot using r2d3

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, shiny-server, r2d3

I am currently having a hard time using `r2d3` with shiny. The problem lays in the sourcing of the script file. Which works if the shiny app is run locally, but not when using `shiny-server`. My understanding so far is that js files should be stored under the `www/`dir and sourced without specifing `www`. However the behaviour is inconsistent if I use the same code on the shiny server[only `d33` renders, other divs are empty or `Error: barchart is not defined` or `www is not defined`] vs running it locally [all three plots show].

Consider following minimal reproducible example:

```
test
├── server.R
├── ui.R
└── www
    └── barchart.js

1 directory, 3 files
```

*barchart.js*
example from r2d3 package

```
// !preview r2d3 data=c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20)

var barHeight = Math.floor(height / data.length);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d * width; })
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * barHeight; })
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
```

*server.R*

```
function(input, output,session) {
    data=c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20)
    output$d31 <- renderD3({
      r2d3( data = data,
            script = "www/barchart.js",d3_version = "5")
    }) 
    output$d32 <- renderD3({
      r2d3( data = data,
            script = "./barchart.js",d3_version = "5")
    }) 
    
    output$d33 <- renderD3({
      r2d3( data = data,
            script = system.file("examples/barchart.js", package = "r2d3"),d3_version = "5")
    }) 
    
}
```

*ui.R:*

```
library(shiny)
library(r2d3)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
            h1("D3 www/barchart.js"),
            d3Output("d31"),
            h1("D3 ./barchart.js"),
            d3Output("d32"),
            h1("D3 system.file"),
            d3Output("d33"),

            
))
```

On the server the two first plot result in empty divs, the thrid method using system file however workes:

[image]

i tried sourcing using `tags$head(tags$script(src="barchart.js"))` which eliminates the not found error but still doesnt show the barplot

#### How can i source the plot file without creating a package and using `system.file`??